# How to remove "%2F" characters in the end of a URL in a form submit

Tags: forms, url, asp.net-core, guid

When submitting a form which gives two GUID values as query string I get `2%F` at the end, making the last GUID an invalid

```
<div>
    <form name="searchbox">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                @{
                    var vStatuses = ViewBag.vStatuses as ICollection<VehicleStatus>;
                    foreach (var vStatus in vStatuses)
                    {
                        <input type="radio" name="status" value=@vStatus.Id />
                        @vStatus.Label
                    }
                }

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @{
                    var vTypes = ViewBag.vTypes as ICollection<VehicleType>;
                    foreach (var vType in vTypes)
                    {

                        <input type="radio" name="type" value=@vType.Id/>
                        @vType.Label
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the form I used. When submitted it will directed to a url like

```
https://localhost:44355/Vehicles?status=f4140f8f-19e2-46d9-8d21-29a9766c0f48&type=c07f4dd0-44d2-4c82-b174-76849d010c95%2F
```

That makes the last GUID invalid I want to have a URL without the last `%2F`

Comment: `%2F` is an URI encode `/`. It looks like something is adding it to the end of the URI path before sending the `POST` request; I'm not sure what though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note there's no space between `vType.Id` and `/` within your code:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value=@vType.Id/>
```

As a result, your above code will be rendered into something as below:

```html
<input type="radio" name="type" value="9abef00b-9391-488a-864a-ece7d9be81ef/">
```

Note the value is `9abef00b-9391-488a-864a-ece7d9be81ef/` instead of a plain GUID (it should be `9abef00b-9391-488a-864a-ece7d9be81ef`).

To fix that, wrap it with a `""` or add an empty space between them :

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="@vType.Id" />
```